# How I can set partly the background color

Tags: android, view, draw, android-canvas, background-color

I have a class that implement a view

```
**DrawView.class**
     public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

 public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
 }
```

and my **file.xml**

```
      <com.example.sliding.DrawView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_listRow_item1"
    android:tag="tv_listRow_item1_1"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:width="100dip"
    android:height="30dip"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_listrow_border"/>
```

This view have 30 dip of height. **How can i color only 30% of this 30 dip?**
Anyone can give me an example?
Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You mean, the top 70% would be transparent, and the rest 30% would be filled with some color?

Comment: Hello Kumar. Thanks for your reply. The view have 80 dip of height. I need a way of color only a few. For example the first 10dip is transparent, the 50 dip follow in black color and the remaining 20dp transparent...This an example...

Comment: And the height 80dp is fixed?

Comment: yes. Each view have 80dip. And need to know how i can color only a few dip that i specify instead of color the 80dip.

Comment: Or...it's possible draw a rectangle inside this view? A rectangle with color....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this will work, but you could make a 9 patch that is 30% color and 70% transparent, then define two stretchable areas (one for each) in the appropriate percentages.  When 9 patches are stretched, they're supposed to respect the ratios of multiple stretch zones, so I think it would work.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Answer (score 0):

One way is by using a LayerDrawable

But this would only work when the heigt of the view is fixed at 80dp.

**Create an xml file in your drawable folder.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
      <shape>
          <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
      </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="10dp">
      <shape >
          <solid android:color="#FF000000"/>
      </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="60dp">
      <shape> 
          <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
      </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**And set this as the background to the view.**

Comment: But this way is fixed. I need a way where i have an integer that is a number of dp treated with a new color.

Comment: I still don't get what exactly is your problem. If you could explain more clearly, may be with a few images, we might have a better solution.

Comment: See my answer bellow kumar :)

Answer (score 0):

I NEED A FUNCTION THAT HAVE  2 PARAMETERS. This FIRST INDICATE THE BEGIN OF COLOR. THE SECOND INDICATE THE END. hEIGHT=80dp. THE FIRST PARAMETER FOR EXAMPLE IS 20 THE SECOND IS 30 FOR EXAMPLE. The pixels inside this interval have a color…..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the easiest way to do it is to override the onDraw(Canvas canvas) function and draw a rectangle like this.

```
    double mStart = -1;
    double mEnd = -1;

    public void addRectangle( double startInPercent, double endInPercent ) {
        if( startInPercent < 0 || endInPercent > 1 || endInPercent > startInPercent )
            return;

        mStart = startInPercent;
        mEnd = endInPercent;

        //this will make the view to refresh the UI
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if( mStart >= 0 && mEnd >= 0)
            canvas.drawRect(0, getHeight() * mStart, getWidth(), getHeight() * mEnd, mPaint);
    }
```

this code will draw a rectangle as specified in the *addRectangle()* method. In my implementation I intend the parameters of that function to per % of the Height of the view.

here is the documentation of that [drawRect( ... )](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRect%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) call. Changing the parameters you can draw at the top, bottom left and right as you prefer.

In order to get the color you want you have to init mPaint in the view constructor like this:

```
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor( Color.RED );
```

of course this is the dumbest code possible, you can play around this 2 concept to basically get what you want.

the main class to do this ( and almost everything in the Andorid UI ) are:

- [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)
- [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)
- [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html)

Comment: Hello Mario. It is possible to inflate this rectangle inside the view that i draw?

Comment: well, to be honest I'm not sure what you mean with "inflate" the rectangle in the view. If you mean to define the rectangle in an xml file I think you can't ( you could, but you'd have to define your xml standard and parser to do so). what you could do for sure is to define a method with 2 parameters. I'll edit the answear to show you the code.